# Поиск члена арифметической прогрессии

Tags: php, математика

Скажите как найти мне номер члена арифметической прогрессии, если мне дано:

> d(шаг) = 1; 
>   Сумма арифметической прогрессии = 50328 или 50000; 
>   Первый член a1 = 100;

Мне нужно как то еще эту формулу записать в PHP (но без цикла а формулой или хотя б минимальным циклом)
По факту номер должен получиться 233 (или приближенное к нему число если принят сумму как 5000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то он состоит в том чтобы найти номер член при котором получилась данная сумма
Sn=a1*n+d*(n-1)*n/2 - решив данное квадратное уравнение относительно n вы получите ответ.

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, можете предоставить решение и как его записать в PHP

Comment: Я не знаю PHP.
формула:n1,2=(-(a1-d/2)+(-)sqrt( (a1-d/2)^2 + 2 * d * Sn))/2
и выбрать подходящий корень.

Comment: Что значит "подходящий корень"?

Comment: У квадратного уравнения 2 корня)
А нам нужен 1
как минимум нам нужны только положительные корни

Comment: Я подставил значения но чтото не получаетсья 233 получаеться 210

Comment: в последней формуле я ошибся
на 2 делить не надо
(-(100-1/2)+sqrt( (100-1/2)^2 + 2 * 1 * 50328)) = 233

Comment: Странно WolframAlpha выдает 233 а вот если запустить на PHP тоже самое что в WolframAlpha то результат другой. Но всеравно спасибо, буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: А если к примеру шаг поставить 2 или 1.2 то чтото не так получаеться.

Comment: Разобрался , в конце нужно делить еще на шаг

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85506/discussion-between-vitali-malinovski-and-sergey-chernykh).